Application.DateDifference gives zero result on MSProject 2024
I'm having a problem calculating date differences in MS Project. For some reason I can't figure out, when I run the code on my machine (Project v2108), Application.DateDifference calculates just fine. But when I run the code on another machine that has Project v2409, Application.DateDifference seems to be giving a zero result in all cases, which then on causes an overflow error.
I'm not getting any errors aside from the overflow, which is caused by a division by zero. Project doesn't complain about permissions or macros active or anything else when running on the problematic machine. It just throws out that zero result. In fact it took me a while to get to what was happening precisely because there were no error messages.
Why am I using Application.DateDifference and not DateDiff (which works just fine on the problem machine)? Mainly because DateDiff doesn't take project calendars into account AFAIK, and I need a calculation which does.
My code looks like this (pseudo'ed for clarity):
    Sub progresscalculation

    (Ask user for the date they want to forecast, check for invalid input, convert variant to date using CDate)

    (Start looping through project tasks, and when you get to a non-summary task...)
    nonsummary_task.Number16 = percent_forecast(start_date, end_date, forecast_date)

    (and the code goes on)
End Sub
Function percent_forecast(start_date As Variant, end_date As Variant, forecast_date As Variant)


    (do some basic checks on the dates, to rule out trivial cases such as 100% complete, 0% complete)
    if not basic_scenario then
            total_time = (Application.DateDifference(start_date, end_date) / (ActiveProject.HoursPerDay * 60))
            spent_time = Application.DateDifference(start_date, Int(forecast_date) + ActiveProject.DefaultFinishTime) _
                / (ActiveProject.HoursPerDay * 60)
            percent_complete = spent_time / total_time
    end if

    percent_forecast = percent_complete

End Function

And that's about it. When I run it on v2108, just fine. When I run it on v2409, all the dates show up just fine, HoursPerDay and DefaultFinishTime are just fine, but total_time and spent_time give a zero result, and the whole thing bombs when calculating percent_complete.

We really need a small snippet of runnable MRE code that does the raw calculation on dates (and someone with MS Project to check it out on different versions). Does the problem machine have the same project calendar defined as the one that works?

Can you reproduce the issue in the Intermediate window with various dates? eg ? Application.DateDifference(date(), date()+1). Do you check to ensure forecast_date is after start_date?

I'll check those two suggestions out, and see what I get. The code was running on the same mpp file, so it should have the same calendar in play. And yes, there's checks in the "do basic checks" that set the values to 1 or 0 if the forecast date is outside the task range.
